# Using values in a column to create a ggvis checkbox

Tags: r, statistics, ggvis

I've been working with some relative data lately trying to make it interactive with ggvis:

```
areas_data %>%
ggvis(~Bacilli, ~Actinobacteria) %>%
layer_points(size := 50, opacity := 0.5, fill = ~area)
```

[image: plot]

I understand that when I need to make an interactive element, I should map the name of the column. However, I am unsure what to do when I want to map the interactive element to the values within a single column. I'm currently trying to make a checkbox for the fill values in the image above. I've written the start of the code, but can't work out the function that will map the column's values to each element of the checkbox. The effect I'm trying to get is that I will be able to interactively colour the body regions that I'm interested in. I've managed to set up the checkbox, but linking it to the data is where I'm stuck.

```
areas_data %>%
ggvis(~Bacilli, ~Actinobacteria) %>%
layer_points(size := 50, opacity := 0.5, fill := input_checkboxgroup(
choices = unique(areas_data$area),
label = "Select areas to colour",
map = function(val) {
# ?
}))
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/movie-explorer.html)? If so, you can see codes. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Kind of, I've had a look at a few of the shiny examples, but I'm kind of stumped at the moment with making fill interactive and mapping it to factors in the column rather than just pointing it as the general name of a column.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use `filter` and `select` (`ggvis`/`dplyr` packages) to limit the choices to the factors from the column of interest. As I am newly exploring these methods, I would probably start with breaking down the data frame first (that's more clear to me right now). But I'm positive this can be done within the `ggivs` function.

```
areas_data <- filter(areas_data, Variable=="value" | Variable=="value")
```

Then drop the unused levels and run in `ggvis`

```
areas_data <- droplevels(areas_data)
areas_data %>$
ggvis(~Bacilli, ~Actinobacteria) %>%
layer_points(size := 50, opacity := 0.5, fill := input_checkboxgroup(
choices = unique(areas_data$area),
label = "Select areas to colour",
map = function(val) {
# ?
}))
```

Comment: I'm interested in trying to generate a completely interactive online plot, I can easily subset the data in code, the thing I'm finding really tricky is performing this filtering with a checkbox.